# caching gridview data in session

Tags: asp.net

I have a reporting page with a gridview and a calendar. When the user loads the page, the default date is today and when he clicks on a date in the calendar control, it loads the reporting data for that day. Each user has a different report and the data is between 300-500 rows per day.

At the moment, I have a linq query that returns the data for a day in the form of a list. Given the relatively small amount of data per query, I'd like to store the result of the query in the session so that I can do the paging and sorting from the session, without going back to the data store.

What I'm looking to do is a list of lists so that when the query loads, the data is saved until the session times out. For instance, if the user selects 4-5 different dates, each of these queries is saved in the session and then if he clicks on one of those dates again, a function first checks to see if the data is in the session: GetQueryFromSession( DateTime TheDate).

I'm stuck on this. How do you create a list of lists that works with the session object. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store a dictionary in the session

```
   private Dictionary<DateTime, System.Data.DataTable> Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session["data"] == null)
            {
                Session[ "data" ] = new Dictionary<DateTime, System.Data.DataTable>();
            }

            return Session[ "data" ] as Dictionary<DateTime, System.Data.DataTable>;
        }
        set
        {
            Session[ "data" ] = value;
        }
    }
```

Then you can keep your result sets per date

You can use a dictionary of lists also
eg:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<YourObject>>
```

your get QueryFromSession method would be similar to this:

```
private DataTable GetQueryFromSession( DateTime TheDate)
{
    return this.Data[TheDate];
}
```

or (if you opted for the List<> option)

```
 private List<YourObject> GetQueryFromSession( DateTime TheDate)
 {
     return this.Data[TheDate];
 }
```

Comment: ok, great. And how does the set work with a dictionary of lists?

Comment: Well you wouldnt use the set to add a result set. you would call this.data.Add(DateTime.Today, YourList/DataTable);  or this.data[DateTime.Today] = YourResultset. You would check if it exists first, then add or amend it

Comment: ok, great! saves a lot of time. I'm not very familiar with the .net framework. Do I need to specify that I'm referring to a list that's in the Session object? Thanks.

Comment: If you add a propery to the page then you will be able to access it as a list by passin the key to the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Session Name, and create a unique key per dataset based on the dates selected?

What you could do is order the dates in descending order, convert them to strings, and concatenate them to form the unique ID.

Then add the data to the session object using the ID.